# Throwing Runtime Exception in SpringBoot triggers Access Denied Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

My springboot application (for blog) is using JWT method of authentication. When user tries to find a blog by the `pageId` which doesn't exist in the repository, I am trying to throw a `NoSuchElementException`

In BlogService:

```
    public BlogResponseDTO findBlogByPageId(String pageId) {
        BlogEntity blogEntity = blogRepository.findByPageId(pageId);
        if (blogEntity == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Blog not found for pageId: " + pageId);
        }
        return buildBlogResponseDTO(blogEntity);
    }
```

But it throws `401 Unauthorized` error as a response.

**WebSecurityConfig**:

```
//Imports
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .exceptionHandling(httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer -> {
                    httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer.authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
                        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                        response.getWriter().write("Authentication failed: " + authException.getMessage());
                    });
                });
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
    

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

My application doesn't throw runtime errors from even though I try throwing it explicitly. Can someone help me with what am I missing? If you need any more details, please drop a comment.

Comment: Whats the reason for not using the built in jwt features of spring security?

Answer (score 1):

To throw a custom exception in Spring using @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler, you need to follow these steps:

1. Create a custom exception class.
2. Create a @ControllerAdvice class to handle exceptions globally.
3. Define methods within @ControllerAdvice class annotated with @ExceptionHandler to handle specific exceptions.

Here's a sample implementation:
Create a custom exception class.

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {
    public CustomException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Create a @ControllerAdvice class to handle exceptions globally.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleCustomException(CustomException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Define methods within @ControllerAdvice class annotated with @ExceptionHandler to handle specific exceptions.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        // Simulating an error condition where you want to throw the custom exception
        throw new CustomException("Custom exception occurred.");
    }
}
```

Now, when you make a request to /api/test, the CustomException will be thrown and handled by the GlobalExceptionHandler, which will return an appropriate HTTP response with the exception message and status code.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime Exceptions are handled from `/error`. This path which wasn't permited according to my `WebSecurityConfig`.

I added `.requestMatchers("/auth", "/error").permitAll()`
to the filterchain, and it works fine now.